# How do I calculate the number of years difference between 2 dates?

Tags: java

How do I calculate the number of years difference between 2 calendars in Java?

Answer (score 21):

First you need to determine which one is older than the other. Then make use of a `while` loop wherein you test if the older one isn't [`after()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#after%28java.lang.Object%29) the newer one. Invoke [`Calendar#add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29) with one (`1`) [`Calendar.YEAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#YEAR) on the older one to add the years. Keep a counter to count the years.

Kickoff example:

```
Calendar myBirthDate = Calendar.getInstance();
myBirthDate.clear();
myBirthDate.set(1978, 3 - 1, 26);
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar clone = (Calendar) myBirthDate.clone(); // Otherwise changes are been reflected.
int years = -1;
while (!clone.after(now)) {
    clone.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
    years++;
}
System.out.println(years); // 32
```

---

That said, the `Date` and `Calendar` API's in Java SE are actually epic failures. There's a new Date API in planning for upcoming Java 8, the [JSR-310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) which is much similar to [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). As far now you may want to consider Joda-Time since it really eases Date/Time calculations/modifications like this. Here's an example using Joda-Time:

```
DateTime myBirthDate = new DateTime(1978, 3, 26, 0, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime now = new DateTime();
Period period = new Period(myBirthDate, now);
int years = period.getYears();
System.out.println(years); // 32
```

Much more clear and concise, isn't it?

Comment: or Years.yearsBetween( myBirthDate, now ).getYears();

Comment: i am unable to create Object of Period. It seems to be private under java.util.time... can you help me out please how can I find difference of year using Period??

Comment: @Mr.Noddy: code snippet is JodaTime not JavaTime. In JavaTime, use `Period#between()`. See also javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html

Answer (score 10):

```
Calendar dobDate; // Set this to date to check
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
int curYear = today.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int curMonth = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int curDay = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

int year = dobDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = dobDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = dobDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

int age = curYear - year;
if (curMonth < month || (month == curMonth && curDay < day)) {
    age--;
}
```

This avoids looping and should be accurate to the day.

Answer (score 2):

```
double diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
double d = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;
return (int) Math.round(diff / d);
```

(java.lang.Math)

Comment: Note: Beware of leap years and other such calendar oddities.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just use `Calendar.getTimeInMillis()`:

```
long msYear = 1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;
long msDiff = c2.getTimeInMillis() - c1.getTimeInMillis();
System.out.println("Years diff: " + String.valueOf(msDiff / msYear));
```

**Edit**
This ignores leap years. But if you are looking for an integer representation of the number of years the leap years are irrelevant for periods shorter than half a millennium or so.

This is plenty of exactness for calculating somebody's age, for example. But not accurate enough to tell their birthday.

If you need your year difference more exact than to three significant digits within a human lifespan (approximately 80.00 years vs 80.05), you should use the "official" solution.

If not, there's no particular reason to put in extra effort for a degree of precision you are not going to use.

Comment: Does this account for leap years, leap minutes, etc?

Comment: Nope. Assuming that if you are looking for multiples of years, you are not overly concerned about a day or two of mismatch. If you look up the exact length of the year in Wikipedia, you can get it as close as you wish over the long run.