# How to display in jlist Every month of specified period?

Tags: java, swing, date, jlist

when the user inputs two dates:
eg: 04/03/2020
10/05/2022

I want to list out every months in between the two dates in jlist.

[preview of my design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNcQi.png)

MY CODE :

```
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
      DefaultListModel lm=new DefaultListModel();
      
     Date s1=new Date(d1.getText());
     Date s2=new Date(d2.getText());
   
    /*
    ADD MONTHS HERE
     */
    
     j1.setModel(lm);
    }
```

Comment: Using your example of 04/03/2020 10/05/2022, assuming the month is the first part of the dates, do you want to list 30 month names with no other context?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. I think that instead you want `YearMonth` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), but which exact class/es from java.time to use depends on your more precise requirements. Also, even if you insist on `Date`, stay far away from the `Date(String)` constructor. It’s been deprecated since 1997 because it works unreliably across time zones.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get list of months & years between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479479/how-to-get-list-of-months-years-between-two-dates). You should want to study the bottom third of [the answer by Sergey Pauk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29480441/5772882) demonstrating how straightforward it goes with java.time.