# Difference of Dates in Java in Years

Tags: java, date, calendar, format, difference

```
Date currentDate=new Date();
DateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");; 
Date date =(Date)formatter.parse(birthDate);     //birthDate is a String, in format dd-MM-yyyy
long diff = currentDate.getTime() - date.getTime();
long d=(1000*60*60*24*365);
long years = Math.round(diff / d);
age=(int) years;
```

The value of age is not returning right. What am I doing wrong?

```
Enter your birthdate: (in format dd-MM-yyyy)
25-07-1992
Current Date: Tue Apr 21 14:05:19 IST 2015
Birthday: Sat Jul 25 00:00:00 IST 1992

Output: Age is: 487
```

Comment: "The value of age is not returning right." For what input and what would you expect?

Comment: You won't get an accurate answer using this method. Use the java.time API or, if you're not using Java 8, use threetenbp

Comment: I am using java 7. I want the age to be in years.

Comment: One problem is there isn't 365 days in every year.

Comment: @weston yes, if I neglect the leap year part, the answer should still be close.. But I am getting an absurd answer

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2846135/335858

Comment: @Baby, I don't want to use another API..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you write `long d=(1000*60*60*24*365);`, the result of `1000*60*60*24*365` will be calculated as `int`, while this is too large for `int` type. You should use `1000l*60*60*24*365` to calculate this.

Comment: Actually "double d=(1000*60*60*24*365.25);" would be more accurate!

Answer (score 4):

It's perhaps surprising to note that you don't need to know how many days or months there are in a year or how many days are in those months, likewise, you don't need to know about leap years, leap seconds, or any of that stuff using this simple, 100% accurate method:

```
public static int age(Date birthday, Date date) {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    int d1 = Integer.parseInt(formatter.format(birthday));
    int d2 = Integer.parseInt(formatter.format(date));
    int age = (d2-d1)/10000;
    return age;
}
```

Comment: I down voted your answer because it thought it was incorrect but I realized I was at fault and now I can't change my vote anymore.

Comment: @SteveS. thanks steve, I've just edited it, and so now you should be able to change the vote :)

Answer (score 2):

As well as issues mentioned in the comments above, this line causes a numeric overflow:

```
long d=(1000*60*60*24*365);
```

Remove that line, and use this instead; you'll get a roughly correct answer:

```
long years = Math.round(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365);
```