# Calculating number of years between two Date or Calendar objects, considering leap years

Tags: java, date, time, calendar, difference

So in a Java project I'm working on we are required to use *only* Date and Calendar objects to represent dates. A method I'm writing requires that a date be at least certain number of years in the past, so I need to be able to accurately calculate the number of years between the present and the given Date or Calendar. I have managed to accurately calculate the number of days between using this implementation:

```
public static long daysSince(Date pastDate) {
    long millisecondsSince = new Date().getTime() - pastDate.getTime();
    return TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(millisecondsSince, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

However I am now struggling to find a way to accurately calculate the number of years between these dates whilst taking into consideration leap years etc. Obviously dividing the result of the above method by 365 or 365.25 does not quite work. I am aware of the joda time package and java.time however we explicitly need to work with Date and Calendar objects. Anyone got any idea how this can be done, preferably as quickly and elegantly as possible? Thank you

EDIT: Seemed to find functioning solution, see below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was finally able to implement the desired functionality using the following code (using some ideas from Haseeb Anser's link):

```
public static int yearsSince(Date pastDate) {
    Calendar present = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar past = Calendar.getInstance();
    past.setTime(pastDate);

    int years = 0;

    while (past.before(present)) {
        past.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
        if (past.before(present)) {
            years++;
        }
    } return years;
}
```

Preliminary tests seem to be getting correct output from this, but I've yet to test more extensively.

Comment: +1 I don't know if it is simpler it depends on what we are comparing because I have no loops in my code which should make my code run faster. But glad you implemented a solution

Answer (score 0):

Check this simple example it might help you:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class GetNumberOfYearsBetweenTwoDate {

    public int getNumberOfYearsBetweenTwoDate(String strDate1, String dateFormat1, 
    String strDate2, String dateFormat2) {
        int years = 0;

        Date date1, date2 = null;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat1);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat2);
        SimpleDateFormat sdfYear = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");

        try {
            date1 = (Date)sdf1.parse(strDate1);
            date2 = (Date)sdf2.parse(strDate2);

            int year1 = Integer.parseInt(sdfYear.format(date1));
            int year2 = Integer.parseInt(sdfYear.format(date2));

            years = year2 - year1;
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        return years;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDate1 = "13-10-1988";
        String dateFormat1 = "dd-MM-yyyy";

        String strDate2 = "2011-10-13";
        String dateFormat2= "yyyy-MM-dd";

        GetNumberOfYearsBetweenTwoDate gnoybtd = new
        GetNumberOfYearsBetweenTwoDate();
        int years = gnoybtd.getNumberOfYearsBetweenTwoDate(strDate1, dateFormat1, 
        strDate2, dateFormat2);

        System.out.println("Number of Years: "+years+" Years"); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't this simply subtract the year value of the past date from the year value of the current date? i.e I could have two dates: the present (2016-25-4) and a past date, say 2015-31-12. With your method this will calculate as 2016-2015 = 1 year passed, however in actuality just short of 5 months has passed. It's crucial for my project that I can calculate the number of years that have passed _to the day_, taking into account leap years. Thanks though

Comment: Have a look at the answers of this question , you might get any valuable help :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846135/how-do-i-calculate-the-number-of-years-difference-between-2-dates

Comment: Thanks. I was able to implement a solution using some of the code you linked. I will add it as an answer.

Comment: @transiti0nary can you please edit this answer and add the new code so that it might help someone else in the future too